# jQuery - How to format readable HTML syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to generate HTML code. The result is injected into a textarea. Afterwards a user can simply copy the result code. My problem is that the generated HTML code has no tabs and linebreaks, making it hard to read.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9NCvd/)

I want it to look like that:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything that you can share with us?

Comment: Like that : http://jsfiddle.net/9NCvd/2/?

Comment: Check out [this SO question, Simple HTML Pretty Print](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348545/simple-html-pretty-print)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `\n` to the end of each line:

http://jsfiddle.net/9NCvd/3/

Note:  You can add tabs.  just use `\t`

Comment: I dont like this answer because it is something that is not programatic, therefore would not work if i pasted html into the text area.  This is why im giving you a downvote.  I am under the assumption that the user doesnt just want to have "textarea" obtain a value, but have the ability to paste html into it for some sort of  line breaking tool, like how jsfiddle formatter might do.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That would take HTML to format, and HTML does not render inside of a textarea. If you want formatting, ditch the textarea and use something else.

Edit: I lied. You just have to insert line breaks `\n` where you want a new line.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add tabs, but you can use `\n` after each line for line breaks and you can simulate tabs with (two or four) spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like:  http://jsfiddle.net/hvuLU/

there is a decode function i created.

```
function myDecode(s){
  return s.replace(/\&lt;/g,"<").replace(/\&gt;/g,">");
}
```

This here, would allow you to do something like:

Paste into textbox to render in a box below it.  Sort of how Stackoverflow has its textarea and then the render area.