# JS library for HTML formatting

Tags: javascript, html, npm, package

Is there at least one good js library which can format an html code string?
I mean, i have a string variable with an html code in it. All i want is to call just one single function from the library to format this long ugly html line into the pretty html code and print it in the textarea.
I was searching on npmjs.com, but nothing was found, maybe i've missed something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple HTML Pretty Print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348545/simple-html-pretty-print)

Answer (score 1):

Instantly found the needed package (at least it works) https://www.npmjs.com/package/beautify